# Add DATE column to store when last read

Tags: sql-server, performance, frequency

We want to know what rows in a certain table is used frequently, and which are never used. We could add an extra column for this, but then we'd get an UPDATE for every SELECT, which sounds expensive? (The table contains 80k+ rows, some of which are used very often.)

Is there a better and perhaps faster way to do this? We're using some old version of Microsoft's SQL Server.

Comment: 80k rows really aren't that many. Are you planning to perform some form of deletion or optimization based on this access information? (it may not yield the benefits you hope for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of logging/tracking is the classical application server's task. If you want to realize your own architecture (there tracking architecture) do it on your own layer.

And in any case you will need application server there. You are not going to update tracking field it in the same transaction with select, isn't it? what about rollbacks? so you have some manager who first run select than write track information. And what is the point to save tracking information together with entity info sending it back to DB? Save it into application server file.

Answer (score 0):

Use another table as a key/value pair with two columns(e.g. id_selected, times) for storing the ids of the records you select in your standard table, and increment the times value by 1 every time the records are selected.

To do this you'd have to do a mass insert/update of the selected ids from your select query in the counting table. E.g. as a quick example:

```
SELECT id, stuff1, stuff2 FROM myTable WHERE stuff1='somevalue';

INSERT INTO countTable(id_selected, times) 
SELECT id, 1 FROM myTable mt WHERE mt.stuff1='somevalue' # or just build a list of ids as values from your last result
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE times=times+1
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is right from the top of my head in MySQL. For conditionally inserting or updating in MSSQL you would need to use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

You could either update the column in the table as you suggested, but if it was me I'd log the event to another table, i.e. id of the record, datetime, userid (maybe ip address etc, browser version etc), just about anything else I could capture and that was even possibly relevant. (For example, 6 months from now your manager decides not only does s/he want to know which records were used the most, s/he wants to know which users are using the most records, or what time of day that usage pattern is etc).

This type of information can be useful for things you've never even thought of down the road, and if it starts to grow large you can always roll-up and prune the table to a smaller one if performance becomes an issue. When possible, I log everything I can. You may never use some of this information, but you'll never wish you didn't have it available down the road and will be impossible to re-create historically.

In terms of making sure the application doesn't slow down, you may want to 'select' the data from within a stored procedure, that also issues the logging command, so that the client is not doing two roundtrips (one for the select, one for the update/insert).

Alternatively, if this is a web application, you could use an async ajax call to issue the logging action which wouldn't slow down the users experience at all.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new column to track `SELECT` is not a practice, because it may affect database performance, and the database performance is one of major critical issue as per Database Server Administration.

So here you can use one very good feature of database called `Auditing`, this is very easy and put less stress on Database.

Find more info: [**Here**](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-database-auditing-techniques/) or [**From Here**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sreekarm/archive/2009/01/05/auditing-select-statements-in-sql-server-2008.aspx?Redirected=true)

Or Search for **`Database Auditing For Select Statement`**